# The element 'value' cannot contain child element 'object' because the parent element's content model is text only

Tags: spring.net

I have a property of `IDictionary` type with key type and value type other than string. Most of the examples given on the internet and in Spring.Net uses string as one of the types.

Here are the config settings:

```xml
<property name="DirectoryServiceAgents">
  <dictionary key-type="OM.ServiceTier.DTO.Transients.AuthenticationDomainIdentifier, OM.ServiceTier" value-type="OM.ServiceTier.Services.User.Internal.IDirectoryServiceAgent, OM.ServiceTier">        
    <entry>
      <key>
        <object type="OM.ServiceTier.DTO.Transients.AuthenticationDomainIdentifier, OM.ServiceTier">
          <constructor-arg type="string" value="${activeDirectory.Domain}"/>
        </object>
      </key>
      <value>
        <object type="OM.ServiceTier.Services.User.Internal.DirectoryServiceAgent, OM.ServiceTier">
          <property name="LDAPPath" value="${activeDirectory.LDAPPath}"/>
          <property name="LDAPContainer" value="${activeDirectory.LDAPContainer}"/>
          <property name="UserName" value="${activeDirectory.UserName}"/>
          <property name="Password" value="${activeDirectory.Password}"/>
        </object>
      </value>
    </entry>
  </dictionary>
</property>
```

I am getting the following `ConfigurationErrorException`:

**Error creating context 'spring.root': The element 'http://www.springframework.net:value' cannot contain child element 'http://www.springframework.net:object' because the parent element's content model is text only.**

Is there something wrong in my config?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if the dictionary configuration supports [inline object definitions](http://www.springframework.net/doc-latest/reference/html/objects.html#objects-inline-object) for keys and/or values. It's not mentioned in the [documentation on setting collection values](http://www.springframework.net/doc-latest/reference/html/objects.html#objects-collections-values).

Could you try this configuration:

```xml
<object>
  <!-- snip -->
  <property name="DirectoryServiceAgents">
    <dictionary 
       key-type="OM.ServiceTier.DTO.Transients.AuthenticationDomainIdentifier, OM.ServiceTier" 
       value-type="OM.ServiceTier.Services.User.Internal.IDirectoryServiceAgent, OM.ServiceTier">        
      <entry key-ref="authDomainId" value-ref="serviceAgent"/>
    </dictionary>
  </property>
  <!-- snip -->
</object>    

<object id="authDomainId" 
        type="OM.ServiceTier.DTO.Transients.AuthenticationDomainIdentifier, OM.ServiceTier">
  <constructor-arg type="string" value="${activeDirectory.Domain}"/>
</object>

<object id="serviceAgent"
        type="OM.ServiceTier.Services.User.Internal.DirectoryServiceAgent, OM.ServiceTier">
  <property name="LDAPPath" value="${activeDirectory.LDAPPath}"/>
  <property name="LDAPContainer" value="${activeDirectory.LDAPContainer}"/>
  <property name="UserName" value="${activeDirectory.UserName}"/>
  <property name="Password" value="${activeDirectory.Password}"/>
</object>
```

Comment: Using <entry key-ref="authDomainId" value-ref="serviceAgent"/> it worked.